# Powershell Get-Service detailed "DESCRIPTION" of the Windows Service

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0, powershell-remoting

Is there a way to get the detailed "DESCRIPTION" of the Service? The below cmdlet can provide all of the properties of Windows Service including display name but it is not getting the "Description"

```
Get-Service | select -Property * | Out-GridView
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Get-Service returns a limited set of information, go to Get-WmiObject win32_service for more:

```
Get-WmiObject win32_service | select * | ogv
```

Comment: Thanks, although apparently, it seems cmdlet for 32 bit Windows I tried that on 64 bit Windows and it worked there fine too!

Comment: Good answer, but `Get-WmiObject` has been superseded by `Get-CimInstance` (and related commands) since Powershell v3. The commands function more or less identically, but `Get-WmiObject` was not developed after Powershell v3 and the command is not available at all on Powershell v6+.

Answer (score 5):

Like say [@mjsqu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3388954/mjsqu) you can not do that with `Get-Service`, if you want just the description of your service, **and print the result in the shell and not in a window**, you can do that for `ssh-agent` for exemple:

**NOT : Like say** [@Bacon Bits](https://stackoverflow.com/users/696808/bacon-bits) **if you are in PowerShell V3 is better if you do that commands with** `Get-CimInstance` **more informations** : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54317765/12317483)

```
Get-WmiObject win32_service | ?{$_.Name -like 'ssh-agent'} | select Description
```

If you want more informations you can run this command. But if you only want the description of the service launch the command above:

```
Get-WmiObject win32_service | ?{$_.Name -like 'ssh-agent'} | select Name, DisplayName, State, PathName, Description
```

---

And if you want this in a window with just the description

```
Get-WmiObject win32_service | select Description | ogv
```

But better with services name

```
Get-WmiObject win32_service | select Name,Description | ogv
```

and for specific service

```
Get-WmiObject win32_service | ?{$_.NAME -like 'ssh-agent'} | select Name,Description | ogv
```

Comment: perhaps you could add _why_ is it better than the previous Answer? [*grin*]

Comment: I had already put it, but I modified my answer for clarity of why I propose this alternative answer

Comment: ah! much more effective ... thanks! [*grin*]

Comment: Thanks @LinkPhoenix, yes these are working for me!

Answer (score 3):

In the standard Windows PowerShell (version <=5.1)

```
Get-WmiObject win32_service | select * | ogv
```

In the Core Powershell Core (version>6)

```
Get-CimInstance  win32_service | ?{$_.Name -like $name} | select Description
```

I also created a [module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ProductivityTools.GetServiceDescription) which returns description for given service.

```
Get-ServiceDescription -name $servicename
```

To install module

```
Install-Module -Name ProductivityTools.GetServiceDescription
```

[image]